# How to check for space in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I am taking baby steps at learning bash and I am developing a piece of code which takes an input and checks if it contains any spaces. The idea is that the variable should NOT contain any spaces and the code should consequently echo a suitable message.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grep`, like this:

```
echo " foo" | grep '\s' -c
# 1
echo "foo" | grep '\s' -c
# 0
```

Or you may use something like this:

```
s=' foo'
if [[ $s =~ " " ]]; then
    echo 'contains space'
else
    echo 'ok'
fi
```

Comment: I wouldn't call out to grep, bash can do it as shown.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 = *[[:space:]]* ]]
then
    echo "space exist"
fi
```

Comment: Pedantically, `==` is the documented pattern matching operator within `[[...]]` but `=` also works

Comment: Thanks, this works well when I want to check an input which contains space in between words. But what if I want to check if a string has space characters at the beginning or at the end of the string?

Comment: use if [[ $var =~ ^[[:space:]] ]] (begin string) and if [[ $var =~ [[:space:]]$ ]] test space at the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

You can test simple glob patterns in **portable** shell by using `case`, without needing any external programs or Bash extensions (that's a good thing, because then your scripts are useful to more people).

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    *' '*)
        printf 'Invalid argument %s (contains space)\n' "$1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

You might want to include other whitespace characters in your check - in which case, use `*[[:space:]]*` as the pattern instead of `*' '*`.

Comment: This has always been my favorite method. It's very effective, and not too hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wc -w` command to check if there are any words. If the result of this output is a number greater than 1, then it means that there are more than 1 words in the input. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1
var2=`echo $var1 | wc -w`
if [ $var2 -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "Spaces"
else
    echo "No spaces"
fi
```

Note: there is a `|` (pipe symbol) which means that the result of `echo $var1` will be given as input to `wc -w` via the pipe.

Here is the link where I tested the above code: https://ideone.com/aKJdyN

Answer (score 1):

You could use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove everything that isn't a space and see if what's left is the empty string or not:

```
var1='has space'
var2='nospace'

for var in "$var1" "$var2"; do
    if [[ ${var//[^[:space:]]} ]]; then
        echo "'$var' contains a space"
    fi
done
```

The key is `[[ ${var//[^[:space:]]} ]]`:

- With `${var//[^[:space:]]}`, everything that isn't a space is removed from the expansion of `$var`.
- [`[[ string ]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) has a non-zero exit status if *`string`* is empty. It's a shorthand for the equivalent `[[ -n string ]]`.

We could also quote the expansion of `${var//[^[:space:]]}`, but `[[ ... ]]` takes care of the quoting for us.